# Default format of XML serialized DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, xml-serialization

I am serializing a DateTime object using the DataContractSerializer class.  I get the following output.

```
2013-05-21T10:50:23.5602265-04:00
```

What is the final component?

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.zzzzzzz-??:??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is your time zone offset.  Greenwich Mean Time - 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If I write the C# code below, I get the current time in the same format as is described:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK")
```